# Trouble triggering actions on iframe load/ready event (jquery)

Tags: jquery, iframe, height

I have an admin panel where I want to upload pictures associated to a product. I have separated the upload to an iframe and the picture preview to another iframe so I don't have to reload the entire page every time a form is submited. Right now it looks like this (added border for reference):

[image]

I'd like to:

- Since the height of both iframes is variable (it depends on the quantity of pictures in the second, and a feedback message is shown on the fist after an upload has been made): set the height of the iframe to fit the height of the body content.
- Show a progress bar gif after the upload form has been submitted, and hide it when the frame has finished loading.
- Reload the preview frame after the upload form has finished loading after a form submit, so it shows the new picture that has been added.

My code looks like this right now:

HTML:

```
<p>
Subir imagen:
<span class="loading_bar"></span><br />
<iframe name="upload_iframe" class="upload_iframe" src="upload.php" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</p>

<p>
<iframe name="slideshow_iframe" class="slideshow_iframe" src="slideshow.php" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
//<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ------------------ UPLOAD ------------------

    // On any frame load
    $("iframe").load(function() {
        // Change frame's height to be the same as the contents body's height
        var iframe_height = $(this).contents().find('body').height();
        $(this).height(iframe_height);
        // Control point
        alert("Frame: "+$(this).attr("class")+" | Content height: "+iframe_height+" | Frame height: "+$(this).height());
    });

    // On "iframe_upload" load
    $("iframe.upload_iframe").load(function() {
        // Hide progress bar
        $(this).prev("span.loading_bar").hide();
        // Reload "iframe_slideshow"
        $("iframe.upload_slideshow").attr("src",$("iframe.upload_slideshow").attr("src"));
    });

    // On "select file" change
    $(".upload_form_upload").change(function() {
        var parent_element = "#"+$(this).closest("form").attr("id");
        // Show progress bar
        $(parent_element+" span.loading_bar", parent.document).show();
        // Submit upload form
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
}); 
//-->
```

Now the trouble:

- The actions under load never trigger, not when the website is first loaded, nor when the form is submitted.
- If i change .load() for .ready(), when the website is loaded everything inside $("iframe").ready() { triggers twice for each iframe and what is under $("iframe.upload_iframe").ready() is never triggered. Even though I get to the alert, the new height is not set.
- This is what I get from the alert under "Control Point":

On page load, first time:

[image]

On page load, second time:

[image]

After submit:

[image]

Comment: Edited some things because I realized that I had not included the js file inside slideshow.php ^^U But the other problems remain.

Comment: Have you considered adding jQuery to the iframe page and using a tiny script there to trigger a custom "loadiframe" event in the parent?

Answer (score 0):

This is my iframe resize script which works cross browser. Hope it helps!

```
//get iframe
var iframe = $('iframe')[0];
//get iframe body (IE?)        
var iframeBody = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument.body : iframe.contentWindow.document.body;
//works out the new height by matching the offsetHeight and scrollHeight
var height = (iframeBody.scrollHeight < iframeBody.offsetHeight) ? iframeBody.scrollHeight : iframeBody.offsetHeight;
//sets the new height on the iframe
$(iframe).height(height);
```